# delete lines based on one file contain to another

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to found a way to speed a delete process.

Currently I've two files, file1.txt and file2.txt

file1 contain records on 20 digits near 10000 lines.
file2 contain length records of 6500 digits and near 2 millions.

My goal is to delete lines on file2 that matches records on file1.

To do this I create a sed file with the record line from the fist file like this:

File1:

> ```
> /^20606516000100070004/d  
> /^20630555000100030001/d  
> /^20636222000800050001/d
> ```

command used :    `sed -i -f file1 file2`

The command works fine but it take about 4hours to delete the 10 000 lines on the file2.

I'm looking for a solution that can speed up the delete process.

Additional information:

each records of file1 is on file2 for sure !
line from file2 always start with a number of 20digits that should match or not with the records contain on file1.

to illustrate the upper point here is a line from file2(this is not the entire line as explain each records of file 2 is 6500 length)

**20606516000100070004**XXXXXXX19.202107.04.202105.03.202101.11.202001.11.2020WWREABBXBOU

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Thanks you for re-working your question to better explain your requirements and provide sample input, output and code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is this, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !(substr($0,1,20) in a)' file1 file2
```

and with files such as you described on a reasonable processor it'll run in a couple of seconds rather than 4 hours.

Just make sure `file1` only contains the numbers you want to match on, not a sed script using those numbers, e.g.:

```
$ head file?
==> file1 <==
20606516000100070004
20630555000100030001
20636222000800050001

==> file2 <==
20606516000100070004XXXXXXX19.202107.04.202105.03.202101.11.202001.11.2020WWREABBXBOU
99906516000100070004XXXXXXX19.202107.04.202105.03.202101.11.202001.11.2020WWREABBXBOU
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !(substr($0,1,20) in a)' file1 file2
99906516000100070004XXXXXXX19.202107.04.202105.03.202101.11.202001.11.2020WWREABBXBOU
```

Comment: well in one word : perfect ! I used awk a lot on all the process but don't know how to use it on this point. You just save my day thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can read the 1st file (containing the 20 first digits) of the files to suppress like this:

```
while IFS= read -r code; do
    < ... process the current code ... >
done < first_file.txt
```

And to process the current code, you should read only the 1st 20 characters of every file. To read these first characters you could use:

```
var=$(head -c 20 $curfile)
```

Then, you can test if the code you read from the 1st file ($code) matches with the first 20 characters you read from $curfile.

```
if [ "$code" == "$var" ] ; then rm -v $curfile ; fi
```

Reading only the 1st 20 characters of every big file is likely to be much faster.

Comment: If I fully understand what you're suggesting that sounds like it'd take many hours longer than the OPs existing command which takes 4 hours as you seem to be suggesting doing 10 thousand iterations of reading 20 chars 1 line at a time from a 2 million line file and comparing them and creating/destroying temp files as you go. It'd probably literally take days to run.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk`, you could try following solution too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} !($1 in arr)' file1 FPAT="^.{20}" file2
```

***Explanation:*** This will give difference of lines(which are not present in file1) by comparing only first 20 characters from file2 and complete line from file1.